# How to link react js app source map to bugsnag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, source-maps, bugsnag

Mapping react js source map to bugsnag

```
bugsnag-source-maps upload-browser \
  --api-key YOUR_API_KEY_HERE \
  --app-version 1.2.3 \
  --base-url http://yourdomain.url/static/js/ \
  --directory build/static/js
```

try to upload source map using above command but whenever new error generated doesn't show exact line of error.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when this is not working it is because the base-url and/or app-version used in the above command does not exactly match the URL and/or app version reported in the event. Please ensure that the URL in the stackframe of the event exactly matches the URL for your uploaded source map. Please also ensure that the app version reported in the event (under the App tab) matches the app version for your uploaded source map.